# How to return list of available contacts using MS communicator in C# Win form app?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, lync-2010

I just downloaded VS 2012 to try create a simple application with a button and a list area. There is a list of contacts I want to store,  So when the button is clicked, the the list gets populated with contacts who all are available in the MS communicator/lync contact list. It doesn't matter if I have to have my communicator/lync running for this app to run.

I did see the *Microsoft Office Communicator Automation API* but am not sure if thats where I would want to start researching further. Please suggest me what direction should I go ahead ( I have nearly no knowledge of C# ) to get this small application done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to show a list of Lync contacts (and just want ALL contacts) then there are WPF/Silverlight controls already built which you can drop into your application. More info here, but there is definitely a ContactList control: http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/05/microsoft-lyncs-development-secret-its-easy/

If you want to get a list of Contact objects though, in order to work with, filter, show differently etc. then have a look at the [Lync Client SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824) which will let you do this. There is a sample of using the SDK to retrieve and publish SelfContact information here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/lync/Lync-2013-Retrieve-and-91ebdca7